# Как правильно копировать новые объекты в list(python3)?

Tags: ооп, python-3.x, разработка-игр, list

Ссылка на проект: https://github.com/LAGx/abstract_game.git
ошибка в game_objects/player/player.py (инициализация в **init**)
и game_objects/bullet/regular.py (отвечает за создание пуль игрока)

собственно вот в чем вопрос:
для того, чтобы можно было выстрелить сразу много независимых пуль я решил создать лист объектов пуль. Это работает, но каждая следующая пуля влияет на направление всех предыдущих

**вот это всё обновляется 60 раз в секунду**(

```
if self.mousepress[0]: #эта штука создает новые объекты и помещает в лист (кстати, мне кажется что здесь и ошибка)
        self.allBullets.append(game_objects.bullet.regular.RegularBullet([ self.pos[0], self.pos[1] ],    list(self.mouse)))

for bullet in self.allBullets:
    bullet.blit(canvas)
```

)

**сам класс RegularBullet:**

```
import phisic.vector
import pygame
from serving.cord import *

class RegularBullet:
    posi = [0, 0]
    vector = phisic.vector.Vector()
    color = [167,34,46]
    speed = 2#30
    isInit = False

    def __init__(self, start = [0,0], end = [0,0]):
        self.posi = start
        self.vector.changeXEx(end[0] - start[0])
        self.vector.changeYEx(end[1] + start[1])
        lenth = self.vector.getLenth()
        self.vector.changeXEx((self.vector.posX)/lenth)
        self.vector.changeYEx((-self.vector.posY)/lenth)
        self.isInit = True


    def blit(self, canvas):
        pygame.draw.line(canvas,self.color, [self.posi[0], -self.posi[1]], [self.posi[0]+self.vector.posX*self.speed*10, -self.posi[1]-self.vector.posY*self.speed*10], 4)
        self.posi[0] += self.vector.posX * self.speed
        self.posi[1] += self.vector.posY * self.speed
```

**и вот пример ошибки:**
сначала стреляю в одну сторону и всё норм:[image: начало]

потом, когда стреляю в другую сторону, ВСЕ пули меняют свое направление:
[image: ошибка!!]

Answer (score 2):

У вас все пули используют один и тот же список, который изменяется в `.blit()` методе.

```
class RegularBullet:
    posi = [0, 0]
```

В этом коде, `posi` создаётся как переменная класса—один объект (список) для всех пуль.

Дополнительно, `def __init__(self, start = [0,0], ...)` значение по умолчанию снова одно для всех переменных класса.

Исправляется созданием своего списка для каждой пули:

```
class RegularBullet:

    def __init__(self, start=None):
        if start is None:
            start = [0, 0]
        self.posi = start
```

Comment: То есть нужно создавать новые объекты и заносить их в список? 
Как это правильно сделать? `self.allBullets.append(copy.deepcopy(game_objects.bullet.regular.RegularBullet([self.pos[0], self.pos[1]], list(self.mouse))))
`

 **через copy.deepcopy() не работает....**

Comment: @LAG_x Тот код, который вы показали в вопросе, содержит как минимум две проблемы (указаны в ответе). 1- Выучите разницу между переменной класса и экземпляра—не используйте переменные класса (если не знаете точно что делаете). 2- Не используйте изменяемые аргументы по умолчанию (практически всегда ошибка). Я показал в ответе пример с posi, вам надо внести изменения для vector, color, etc.